# Explain query that involves for loop with select statement and includes running of jobs

Tags: oracle, plsql

```
begin
for i in (select job from user_jobs where job=3309 and what like '%LEDGER_REPORT%')
loop
dbms_job.run(i.job);
end loop;
end;
/
commit;
begin
for i in (select job from user_jobs where job=3309 and what like '%LEDGER_REPORT%')
loop
dbms_job.broken(i.job,TRUE);
end loop;
end;
/
commit;
```

can someone explain how this works? i am new to this so I expect an explanation that is easy to understand for a beginner like me.

Comment: What *exactly* do you not understand? The `FOR` loop? The `dbms_job` call?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
--start of the anon block
begin
-- selecting the rows that match this query (will likely only ever be one)
for i in (select job from user_jobs where job=3309 and what like '%LEDGER_REPORT%')
-- now we have 'i' which is a table record type, with 'job' as the only column/value
loop
-- for each record found, do dbms_job.run(). Pass in the value from our FOR loop
dbms_job.run(i.job);
end loop;
end;
/
commit;
-- commit makes sure the job is running
begin
-- same as above...
for i in (select job from user_jobs where job=3309 and what like '%LEDGER_REPORT%')
loop
-- now we set the job status to BROKEN, which means it won't be run again unless manually called
dbms_job.broken(i.job,TRUE);
end loop;
end;
/
commit;
```

It could use some optimization, a very round about way of doing things, but there it is. Feel free to ask for any other clarifications. The dbms_job procedures are Oracle packaged procedures, you can find more details on them online.